# Simple pendulum. quick question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

[image]

I was trying to find an equation to find $T$ and $\omega$ for a simple pendulum when in an elevator while the elevator is accelerating. One scenario is when it accelerates in the positive up direction and another in the negative down direction, and another when it accelerations at $g$ which is also negative.

$$\begin{aligned}
   T =& \frac{2 \pi}{\omega}
\\ \omega =& \frac{2 \pi}{T}
\\ T =& 2 \pi \sqrt{L/g}.
\end{aligned}$$

$L$ is the string length. 
Is this right?

Answer (score 1):

Those equations are rather tautological. The gist is that it doesn't matter whether you have some acceleration or gravitational attraction, they're really indistinguishable. So you basically get a $g' \equiv g + a$ as new "compound down acceleration".

Then you write down the *exact* same equations as for the earth-rest-frame case, but with this modified $g'$ constant. You *can* then again write the result in terms of $g$ and $a$, but as I said that's more or less tautological.

Comment: actually, I found the answer.